# For loop not running

Tags: arduino-uno

I've been trying to get a for loop to run 9 times using the below code but can't get the loop to run.

```
void output() {
  int r;
  r = 1;
  Serial.println("Output");
  digitalWrite(Latch, LOW);
  for (int r=1; r >= 9;  r = r + 1) {
    Serial.println("Test");
    digitalWrite(DataOutput, Q[r]);
    digitalWrite(ClockPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ClockPin, LOW);
  }
  Serial.println("Done For");
  digitalWrite(Latch, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Latch, LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
for (int r=1; r >= 9;  r = r + 1) {
```

to

```
for (int r=1; r <= 9;  r = r + 1) {
```

The for loop will only run while the second part is true.

Answer (score 1):

The middle expression r => 9 in the for loop is wrong. This will only loop whilst r is greater than 9 and you are starting from r = 1. Change it to r <= 9.